# I cant remove ion-input padding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I try this

```
<ion-item style="padding:0px !important;" >
```

or html

```
  <ion-item class="no-padding"  >                   
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="siparis.urun.stok_adi" type="text"  ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

scss

```
 .no-padding {
      padding: 0px !important;
    }
```

but didnt remove input padding 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT3Xu.png)

Comment: cant see the image.. its blocked

Comment: padding in `<ion-content>` can u check it please

Comment: ion content has no effect.

i replace image

Comment: open the app with the devtools attached and check which tag inside of the ion-input has the padding, then copy the selector path with right click and paste it on your sass file and remove the padding.